# 'GATSBY_CONCURRENT_DOWNLOAD' is not recognized as an internal or external command on Windows

Tags: wordpress, windows, gatsby

I'm using gatsby for my project with wordpress as a backend.
It keeps running forever when I do `gatsby develop`

So I tried `GATSBY_CONCURRENT_DOWNLOAD=50 gatsby develop`

But it gives this Error o
`'GATSBY_CONCURRENT_DOWNLOAD' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: What version of Gatsby are you running?

Answer (score 1):

So this was a problem of Enviornment Variables, On MacOs and Linux if you write the Enviornment variables before calling the actual script it works fine but on windows to have the same working you need to install a node package

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env